# How to find errors in a file using for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How I can find errors (Error1, Error2 , Error 3) from a file using `for` loop.

A file contains three types of errors (`strings`) from `4` different machines. Any machine can have any number of errors. `whiptail` is used to create a `pop-up window` whenver an error is found.

```
#!/bin/sh

 
if grep -R "Error1 in Machine 1" /home/new/Report.txt
then
echo "Error1 found in Machine 1"
whiptail --title "Report Error" --msgbox "Error 1 in Machine 1" 8 78
else
echo "No Error found"
fi


if grep -R "Error2 in Machine 1" /home/new/Report.txt
then
echo "Error2 found in Machine 1"
whiptail --title "Report Error" --msgbox "Error 2 in Machine 1" 8 78
else
echo "No Error found"
fi


if grep -R "Error2 in Machine 2" /home/new/Report.txt
then
echo "Error2 found in Machine 2"
whiptail --title "Report Error" --msgbox "Error 2 in Machine 2" 8 78
else
echo "No Error found"
fi


if grep -R "Error3 in Machine 3" /home/new/Report.txt
then
echo "Error3 found in Machine 3"
whiptail --title "Report Error" --msgbox "Error 3 in Machine 3" 8 78
else
echo "No Error found"
fi
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `-R` option in `grep`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 3 errors and 4 machines you can use nested loops to handle all 12 combinations:

```sh
for ((e = 1; e <= 3; e++)); do
  for ((m = 1; m <= 4; m++)); do
    message="Error$e in Machine $m"
    if grep -qF "$message" /home/new/Report.txt; then
      echo "$message"
      whiptail --title "Report Error" --msgbox "$message" 8 78
    else
      echo "No Error found"
    fi
  done
done
```

The `grep` options `q` (quiet) and `F` are used to not print anything and to interpret the pattern as a fixed string, not a regular expression.

Comment: Renaus Pacalet Thank you for the reply. As whiptail is used in for loop, the code will pop up a window whenever an error is found in the file. How whiptail can be used out of for loop so that it shows a list of all errors in the file. For example if I get e1 in m1, e2 in m3 and e3 in m3. How all these 3 errors can be shown in one pop up window.

Comment: This is different from your question. SO is also for others that could encounter similar problems, so questions and answers must be perfectly synchronized. Please first edit your question and explain that you want only one pop up window (not several as in your current question) and clearly explain what the message should look like when there is only one error but also when there are several. Do not explain this in comments, only in your question.

Comment: I edited my question now. Could you please check now

Comment: Sorry but your question (at least the version I can see) still does not explain that you want only one call to `whiptail` and it does not explain what message you want to see in the pop up window when there are several errors.

Comment: Renaud Pacalet, I created a new question with some details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70188150/how-to-print-list-of-strings-in-a-pop-up-window-and-save-the-strings-in-a-file-w?noredirect=1#comment124073746_70188150

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

grep 'Error[1-3] in Machine [1-4]' /home/new/Report.txt |
while IFS= read -r errmsg
do
        whiptail --title "Report Error" --msgbox "$errmsg" 8 78
done
```

The script doesn't put the "No error found" message (no news is good news), but otherwise should work.

Comment: That will pop-up more error messages than needed

Answer (score 0):

Pass `grep`(1) one time and save the output, then do the rest.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t error_message < <(grep 'Error[[:digit:]] in Machine [[:digit:]]' /home/new/Report.txt)

((${#error_message[*]})) || { printf >&2 'No error message found\n'; exit; }

for message in "${error_message[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\n' "$message"
  whiptail --title "Report Error" --msgbox "$message" 8 78
done
```