# How to print list of strings in a pop up window and save the strings in a file with time stamp

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, rhel, whiptail

When I run below script, it reads a report.txt file and whenever a message is matched in the file a `pop up` window will come with the message. How `whiptail` can be used out of `for` loop so that pop up windows comes only once with list of all messages. And `the strings` to be saved in a file with `time stamp`.

```
for ((e = 1; e <= 3; e++)); do
  for ((m = 1; m <= 4; m++)); do
    message="Error$e in Machine $m"
    if grep -qF "$message" /home/new/Report.txt; then
      echo "$message"
      whiptail --title "Report Error" --msgbox "$message" 8 78
    else
      echo "No Error found"
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: Cyrus. i use linux red hat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove line with `whiptail` and replace last `done` with:

```
done | whiptail --title "Report Error" --msgbox "$(< /dev/stdin)" 15 78
```